# Add a subitem to Woocommerce section

Tags: plugins

I want to add a subitem to "Woocommerce" parent item, below "Orders", this subitem is a custom post type.

[image]

I tried to use `(in $args)`:

```
$args = array('show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order');
register_post_type('my_posttype', $args);
```

But it doesn't work, I tried with another section ex. 'edit.php?anotherpage' and it works.

[image]

Any idea?!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Short answer, use:

```
$args = array('show_in_menu' => 'woocommerce');
register_post_type('my_posttype', $args);
```

But this won't give you the custom post type submenus.

You can also use [`add_submenu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/), the code below is just an example:

```
function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page', 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback' ); 
}
function my_custom_submenu_page_callback() {
    echo '<h3>My Custom Submenu Page</h3>';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page',99);
```

You need a high(er) priority number to execute it later then the `woocommerce_admin_menu` function, which has 9, and there is `woocommerce_admin_menu_after`, which has 50 - those functionbs are in `woocommerce-admin-init.php`.