# how to make settings page for woocommerce plugin?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm working on a woocommerce plugin, I want to make a different settings page for the plugin ( not the default settings page that woocommerce provides ).

Plugin's setting page lies on the woocommerce menu ( along with Products, Orders, Coupons, Myplugin,... )

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has a great [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/) resource available online. This should always be your goto WooCommerce development, API, hook, filter, and action resources.

But your question is more to WordPress and has actually been asked and answered before [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101773/add-a-subitem-to-woocommerce-section).

Comment: thanks, actually I've made a submenu to woocommerce menu in the dashboard.
now I want to add sections, settings to the plugin page and be able to save the data entered in the fields. This is what I'm not able to do. I hope this clarifies the issue.